# Marginal distribution of multivariate random variable

Tags: integration, random-variables

I have a multivariate random variable with densitsy function

$$f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{1 - \cos(x_1)\cos(x_2)\cos(x_3)}{8\pi^3} \text{ with }0 \le x_1,x_2,x_3 \le 2\pi $$

I now want the marginal distribution of $x_1$ and $x_2$

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac1{8\pi^3} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1 - \cos(x_1) \cos(x_2) \cos(x_3) \, dx_3$$

which leads me to:

$$\frac1{8\pi^3}\left[x_3 - \cos(x_1)\cos(x_2)\sin(x_3)\vphantom{\frac11}\right]_0^{2\pi}$$

Now according to my book this should evaluate to $1/4\pi^2$ but i just don't see how the cosinus-sinus term can be zero, which would be required to get to that result. Could someone explain to me how that term evaluates to zero or i have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you have evaluates to (Substitute the bounds for the variable $x_3$!) $$\frac{1}{8 \pi^3} \left[x_3-\cos x_1 \cos x_2 \sin x_3\vphantom{\frac11}\right]_0^{2 \pi} = \frac{1}{8 \pi^3} (2 \pi - 0-\cos x_1 \cos x_2 (\sin (2 \pi)-\sin 0)).$$ The sines of $0$ and $2 \pi$ will vanish; you will get the desired result.

Comment: But sin(2*$\pi$) - sin(0) is not 0. Why do the sines vanish?

Comment: $\sin(2\pi)=0$ and $\sin0=0$.  Is it possible that you're finding the sine of $2\pi$ _degrees_ instead of $2\pi$ _radians_? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes that's it. Thx.